# GitHub won't accept this old commit. How do I fix it?

Tags: git, github, mercurial, hg-git

I am in the process of converting a Mercurial repository to Git, to be hosted on GitHub. The conversion with hggit seemingly went well, but trying to push to GitHub failed:

```
remote: error: object 27124f1fc9f51aed184f61c33dc9073f64bf95ba: 
nulInCommit: NUL byte in the commit object body

remote: fatal: Error in object
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Broken pipe KiB/s
```

Apparently, what is causing the error is one particular checkin done in Mercurial with a named branch that is empty (the branch name is an empty string).

So what is the best way to fix this? I envision having to strip the problematic commit from the repository, and then somehow re-apply the 1000 or so succeding commits.

[image: commit graph]

I suppose this could be done either in Mercurial og Git, and I would welcome suggestions for either one on how to strip out the offending commit.

Comment: You say that the push failed, but you don't show any failing push. It seems likely that hggit made a weird (invalid) Git branch name out of the empty Mercurial name, but if so, it should be trivial to rename the Git branch to a valid name on the Git side.

Comment: Failed how? Did you get an error message?